# Preload resource assembly?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I have a combo box on a window that uses an external resource assembly for it font and it's operating really slowly (7-8 seconds to pull down).

```
<ComboBox ItemTemplate="{StaticResource LangComboboxItemTemplate}" 
x:Name="Lang_Cbx" Width="295" ItemsSource="{Binding Locales}" Height="32" 
FontFamily="/FontLibrary;component/Fonts/Font.CompositeFont#Font"
SelectedValue="{Binding CurrentLanguage}"  SelectedValuePath="LocaleId"  
/>
```

When I remove the 'FontFamily' attribute the combo box operates as expected.

Is there a better way?  Possibly to preload the resource assembly?

(Using VS2010 & .Net 4.0,  The resource assembly is about 40MB.)

Answer (score 1):

In App.xaml:

```
<Application.Resources>
    <FontFamily x:Key="FontFamilyComboBox">/FontLibrary;component/Fonts/Font.CompositeFont#Font</FontFamily>
</Application.Resources>
```

In the view:

```
FontFamily="{DynamicResource FontFamilyComboBox}"
```

This will cause the resource to be loaded at application startup (you'll "pay" those 7-8 seconds then) but the combo will behave as expected.

You can also use `StaticResource` instead of `DynamicResource` but if the loading of the assembly is so slow the view might start initialization before the resource is available and cause an exception to be thrown.

Comment: Thanks for your help but I couldn't make this work.  The delay was always encountered the first time the font was used.  I added a single character to the startup splash screen and the delay was added at startup.